# Python string comparison won't match forward slash

Tags: python, string, comparison

A simple question usually has a simple answer but I am struggling to find it. Can someone please explain why the following isn't matching?

```
string = 'HTTP/NONE'
if string is 'HTTP/NONE': print 'match'
```

Comment: possible duplicate of [Python '==' vs 'is' comparing strings, 'is' fails sometimes, why?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1504717/python-vs-is-comparing-strings-is-fails-sometimes-why)

Answer (score 3):

Use::

```
string = 'HTTP/NONE'
if string == 'HTTP/NONE':
    print 'Match!'
else:
    print 'No Match!'
```

Works for me. Apparently, strings like ==

Comment: You misunderstand what `is` *means*. `int`s 'like' `==` too.. Testing for equality is a very different operation from testing for identity. Two 1 dollar notes have the same *value*, but they are still two separate pieces of paper. They are equal, but have separate identities.

Comment: @jamylak: sorry 'bout the semicolons, come from a C background XD

Comment: @BinayakaChakraborty You still aren't allowed to use them!

Answer (score 2):

Use `==` instead. Also be wary not to name a variable the same name as a python module.

```
>>> mystr = 'HTTP/NONE'
>>> mystr is 'HTTP/NONE'
False
>>> mystr == 'HTTP/NONE'
True
```

The `is` operator tests for *identity* - and only returns `True` for objects that have the same `id`. `==` only checks if the two objects have the same value, which is what you want here. If we check the `id`s of `mystr` and `'HTTP/NONE'`, we can see they are different.

```
>>> id(mystr)
64342000
>>> id('HTTP/NONE')
64341360
```

Comment: Rule of thumb: If you can't explain what `is` does, don't use it.

Answer (score 2):

`is` tests for identity. From the [Python Documentation](http://docs.python.org/2/reference/expressions.html#is):

> The operators `is` and `is not` test for object identity: `x is y` is true if and only if x and y are the same object. `x is not y` yields the inverse truth value.

When dealing with comparing values you're better of using `==`. Example ipython session:

```
In [1]: s = 'A/B'

In [2]: s == 'A/B'
Out[2]: True

In [3]: s is 'A/B'
Out[3]: False

In [4]: b = 'A/B'

In [5]: s is b
Out[5]: False

In [6]: b == s
Out[6]: True
```

---

Given that the identity operator checks the id of the objects compared, its result has quirks because Python caches `int`, `float`, small strings. This is visible by calling the [`id()`](http://docs.python.org/2/library/functions.html#id) function:

```
In [28]: s1, s2 = 'Joe', 'Joe'

In [29]: id(s1), id(s2)
Out[29]: (21399760, 21399760)

In [30]: s1 is s2
Out[30]: True
```

As you can see, in this case, even though they were created by different assignment operations, both `s1` and `s2` are *the same object*.

[Here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/306353/147072)'s a similar case with int objects, related to [this](http://docs.python.org/2/c-api/int.html#PyInt_FromLong) explanation from the Python documentation:

> The current implementation keeps an array of integer objects for all integers between -5 and 256, when you create an int in that range you actually just get back a reference to the existing object.

I didn't find the explanation for the string type, but I assume the same is going on, and as such `is` shouldn't be used for value comparison. It might sometimes return `False` and sometimes `True`:

```
In [39]: s = 'Joe'

In [40]: id('Joe')
Out[40]: 21403136

In [41]: id(s)
Out[41]: 21403136

In [42]: s is 'Joe'
Out[42]: True
```

Good luck!

Answer (score 1):

You are testing for identity, not equality. Use `==` instead.

You are confusing identity with equality. Two 1 dollar banknotes have the same value, so they are equal when it comes to buying a donut. But they each have a separate identity.

To help performance, sometimes Python uses the same object when you tell Python to store the same literal value. This is called *interning*, and when that happens, you get a reference to an `int` or a `str` value that just *happens* to be the same object too.

`is` tests for identity; it is basically implemented as `id(a) == id(b)`, two references are identical if the identity of their values is equal. The are referring to the *same object*, not just the same *value*.

Answer (score 0):

```
string = 'HTTP/NONE'
if string == 'HTTP/NONE': print 'match'
```

It will work.